# Rails Routing: URL won't change even after using friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I've been trying for the past 2 days but ultimately failed. I would like to get a URL like this: `dresses/type/flower-girl` but all I've got is `/dresses/type/4`

I've got `Shop has_many Dresses` and `Type has_many Dresses`. In my `Dress` table, I've got `type_id` column which reference to the `Type` table.

This is my code:

```
# Routes file
resources :dresses 
match '/dresses/type/:id' => 'dresses#type'
```

---

```
# Type.rb model
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

---

```
# Dresses Controller
def index
  @types = Type.all
end

def type
  @dresses = Dress.find_all_by_type_id(params[:id])
end
```

---

```
# View (index.html.erb)
<% @types.each do |type| %>
  <%= link_to type.name, :action => "type", :id => type.id %>
<% end %>
```

---

I've also tried using `:name` to replace `:id` in the routes, controller & view but they produced `/dresses/type/Flower%20Girl` instead.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, in your index view, change this 
`<%= link_to type.name, :action => "type", :id => type.id %>` to 
`<%= link_to type.name, :action => "type", :id => type.slug%>`

I suppose friendly_id doesn't magically support custom routes, so you might end up looking for records by slug instead of id in your controller.

Comment: If I rename all the values in the name column using hyphen then the hyphenated words will appear everywhere in my app. Besides, the slug column with the friendly_id gem have already taken care of that, I just want the gem to use the values in the slug column, which it failed (or maybe I mess up the routing).

Comment: Homey-schmomey, it works! Why didn't I think of that? Anyway, thanks man. :)

Comment: I've changed `:id` to `:slug` in the routes, controller & view file. It feels kind of... the right way to do it.